# Irreducible representation : question of the definition

Tags: group-theory

On the french page of wikipedia it is said that an irreducible representation is a representation that has only $V$ and ${0}$ as stable spaces.

But as I understood (it is very basic understanding of the notion I didn't really read a book about it), a representation is a map :

$$ \rho : G \rightarrow V $$

Where $G$ is a group, V a vector space, and $\rho$ verifies $\rho(g_1*g_2)=\rho(g_1) \circ \rho(g_2) $

I can see what $\rho(g_1)$ is stable for a given subspace $W$ but what does that mean that $\rho$ is stable for $W$ ?

Does that mean that $\forall g ~  \rho(g)(V) \subset V$ (ie we have to say "for all g") ?

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right. $W \subseteq V$ is a stable space under the representation $\rho$ iff $\rho(g)W \subseteq W$ for every $g \in G$.

Comment: Great thank you a lot